# Python: got unicode with "\xf3" (ó). Want to convert to str ó. How?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using an API and in the response I get a unicode with \xf3. I want to cast it to a string but I get an error. Python 2.7, btw.

Edit:

To make it more clear:
Let's say I have a dictiory with keys including strings with an 'ó'

```
a = {'camión': 3}
```

I'm trying to check if a unicode object with "\xf3" is a key of the dict. So, for example, I try using:

```
u"cami\xf3n" in a
```

That returns False. If I try to print that unicode object I get "camión", but I can't do a simple cast to get there (exception).

So, I'm asking how to pass from u"cami\xf3n" (unicode) to "camión" (string) and be able to pass the condition before

Comment: This question is impossible to answer like this. "\xf3" *is* that character: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: You are probably looking at the **`repr()` representation output**; don't confuse that output (which is meant for debugging purposes and allows you to *recreate* the same value easily) with the actual contents. All this means you **already** have the right character, but are instead struggling to print the string contents instead of the representation.

Comment: I edited the original question to make clearer my problem

Comment: why not just use  unicode strings as keys?

Answer (score 4):

What encoding are you using ? With strings and unicode, there's no such thing as "casting", you want to encode (unicode to string) or decode (string to unicode) using a given encoding (hint: always using utf-8 is your safest bet).

Once you know which encoding you are using, you just have to decode / encode as you whish, ie:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bytekey = "éà" # using my default system encoding => utf-8
>>> a = {bytekey: 42}
>>> a
{'\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa0': 42}
>>> bytekey in a
True
>>> ukey = u"éà"
>>> ukey
u'\xe9\xe0'
>>> ukey in a
False
>>> ukey.encode("utf-8")
'\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa0'
>>> ukey.encode("utf-8") in a
True
>>>
```